# Hide the Navigation Bar in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How do I disable/hide the Navigation Bar in Visual Studio 2017? [The bar shows the Project, Class, Method/attribute where the cursor is placed].

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Navigation bar enabled:

[image]

Disable it in `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#` (or `All Languages`) and press OK:

[image]

...and it's gone:

[image]