# I lost the code navigation dropdowns in Visual Studio. How can I get them back?

Tags: visual-studio

The following is an example screenshot from Microsoft:

[image: Visual Studio]

I have lost the dropdowns shown in the red rectangle.  I can't figure out how to get them back.  Can anybody help me?

Comment: Check out this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56916995/432074

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide the Navigation Bar in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346586/hide-the-navigation-bar-in-visual-studio)